# Как поставить точку на ссылке в редакторе WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Появилась надобность поставить точку на ссылке в старом редакторе WordPress. Cейчас, когда я хочу поставить точку, система автоматически преобразует точку в тире. Возможно ли технически реализовать это?

Comment: Нет, не получится.

Comment: Да, это можно сделать через фильтр функции sanitize_title()

Comment: В слаге что ли? Или где "в редакторе"?